# Launching FancyBox automatically on Magento

Tags: magento, fancybox, pageload

I know this was asked before but i couldn't get it to work anyhow. What I am trying to do is to launch FancyBox on page load(on Magento). Seems simple enough but as I am not very familiar with JQuery, i am having some problems. The Code I got the work with manually clicking on the anchor is as follows:

```
    <!-- FancyBox -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){   

    jQuery("a[rel=fancybox]").fancybox({            

    });

    });
    </script>
    <!-- FancyBox -->

    <p><a id="image_id" href="http://shop2.xsmoke.com/skin/frontend/infinitus/maxxi/images/logo-300x71.png" rel=iframeLink><img src="http://shop2.xsmoke.com/skin/frontend/infinitus/maxxi/images/logo-300x71.png" alt="" /></a></p>
```

What I have so far regarding automatic launch is:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){   

    $("#image_id").fancybox().trigger('click');

    });
```

The rest is same. Can anyone help?

EDIT: Ok i have been trying to get it to work for hours now and I tried using plain JavaScript for clicking the anchor. I Wrote

```
    function init(){

        document.getElementById("image_id").click();

    }

    window.onload = init;
```

but it still doesn't click the anchor. When I try it on a basic html page locally it works, but on the Magento home-content.phtml on the server it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`? ... notice the dollar `$` sign inside function since you are doing `$("#image_id")` later in your script. Also, this `jQuery("a[rel=fancybox]").fancybox()` is doing nothing unless you have some elements with `rel="fancybox"` elsewhere in your html code

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){   

    jQuery("a[rel=fancybox]").fancybox({});
    jQuery("a[rel=iframeLink]").fancybox({});
    $("#image_id").trigger('click');

});

 <p>
  <a id="image_id" href="http://shop2.xsmoke.com/skin/frontend/infinitus/maxxi/images/logo-300x71.png" rel="iframeLink">
   <img src="http://shop2.xsmoke.com/skin/frontend/infinitus/maxxi/images/logo-300x71.png" alt="" /></a></p>
```

Comment: add rel="fancybox" in your id="image_id" tag.

Comment: am i allowed to have 2 rel tags?

Comment: `rel=iframeLink` should be `rel="iframeLink"` in the html code